# In gtk, how can I switch to a new screen with new buttons, and other widgets, but on the same window?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gtk, gtk2

In gtk, I am trying to make a game that displays the creator in big letters for 3 (three) seconds before displaying the main menu. I know that nothing is wrong /w the function `DisplayMainMenu`. For some reason this makes it just show the Asadefa screen for ever. How can I fix?

```
#define NOTHING
#define EMPTYSTRING "\0"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    Window = gtk_window_new(0);
    Box = gtk_hbox_new(00, 00);

    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(Window), 1);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(Window),800, 500);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(Window), "Fakecraft" );
    g_signal_connect(Window, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(Window),16);

    char *TXT=("<span font=\"72\">ASADEFA </span>");
    GtkWidget (*Label) = gtk_label_new(EMPTYSTRING);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Window), Box);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Box), Label);
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(Label), TXT);

    gtk_widget_show_all(Window);
    gtk_main( NOTHING NOTHING );

    sleep(3);

    DisplayMainMenu();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `sleep`. GTK+ uses an event loop to react to event, so you won't reach your `sleep` call until `gtk_main_quit` has been called, which is already too late. You're supposed to use [`g_timout_add_seconds`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds) instead to add an event source that will call your callback after your 3 seconds. In that callback, you can call your `DisplayMainMenu` function.

Comment: solved my problem, but you could have told me that g_timeout_add_seconds goes before gtk_main

Comment: To be clear: nothing should ever go after the `gtk_main` call. `gtk_main` is what runs the event loop that continuously checks what events GTK+ need to be process. Once you call `gtk_main_quit`, you exit the event loop and get out of `gtk_main`, so everything you do after that point won't be processed by GTK+. See [event loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop).